# Why this ip range is only showing * * *?

Tags: ip, traceroute

I've got a question.

When I try to do this on GNU/Linux:

```
traceroute -m 255 -I [the_ip]
```

Then I get this:

```
192.0.0.1 (192.0.0.1)  6.788 ms  6.774 ms  6.781 ms
62.214.36.201 (62.214.36.201)  7.672 ms  7.869 ms  7.872 ms
62.214.37.202 (62.214.37.202)  12.351 ms  12.460 ms  12.467 ms
80.249.210.13 (80.249.210.13)  42.244 ms  42.202 ms  42.385 ms
87.110.223.130 (87.110.223.130)  45.054 ms  42.502 ms  42.456 ms
87.110.254.237 (87.110.254.237)  46.880 ms  46.434 ms  46.394 ms
* * *
HostBaltic.balt-ix.net (77.241.206.86)  42.506 ms  42.175 ms  42.117 ms
* * *
* * *
* * *
* * *
* * *
[...]
```

https://pastebin.com/tXq78aEV

Comment: This seems to be related:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127002/traceroute-gives-only-stars-how-to-fix

Answer (score 0):

Traceroute expects a response to packets for each hop. If it does not receive that, it will output an asterisk.

If you want to see the route but not care about those responses try looking at `mtr` instead.

Comment: Helo, thanks for your answer. After 374 sent packets mtr doesn't stop anymore. Why? Is there a loop in the network ip?

Comment: mtr continues to monitor. Just ctrl-C it when you have seen what you need